# Why does Exley link Jack’s motive to the Night Owl events?

Tags: plot-explanation, la-confidential

In the records room, after the brawl between Exley and Bud White over
Lynn Bracken had settled down, Exley expresses his views to Bud White
that three African American men were wrongly framed as Night Owl
suspects by Dudley because they had criminal records in the past:

> Exley: He knew there'd be no questions asked......if they were killed resisting
> arrest. **Somehow this is all connected to Jack's angle**. Sid Hudgens......the pictures
> to blackmail Ellis Loew....A kid got murdered.

Exley believes that there is a connection between the events he is describing
and the perspective or motive of the character Jack.

Why does Exley link Jack’s motive to the Night Owl events?